# "Why are you still making fun of me?" I have embarrassed myself enough - does it serve the purpose of trying to make a point

Tags: meaning, questions

**Example 1**

> "They are not taking advantage of the opportunities. **Why did they come to the country?** That's stupid."

**Example 2**

> **Why are you still making fun of me?** I have embarrassed myself enough.

I don't know if this kind of question can be seen as a rhetorical question or not. But they serve the purpose of trying to make a point, I think.

My question is: do they serve the purpose of trying to make a point? What are they called?

Comment: Where do your example sentences come from?

Comment: They do seem like rhetorical questions, though they *could* be seen as trying to elicit an answer, if one stretches one's credibility. A more obviously rhetorical question, "Why don't you study? Do you wish to fail this course?" See https://www.grammarly.com/blog/rhetorical-question/

Answer (score 2):

Almost any question could be either a rhetorical or standard question.

If you ask a question, but then answer it yourself and continue talking... or ask a question, don't allow anyone an opportunity to answer, and continue some logical argument, then it's a "rhetorical question".

That usually means it is "trying to make a point".

The same exact question could be real, if you posed it to the listener in a questioning tone of voice and waited for them to reply.

In your examples, it's not completely certain, but the speaker does seem to be answering their own question, and not waiting for a reply. They are asking a question for effect, to make a point. We would need more context to know for sure. If they turned to the other person and demanded an answer, then it would be a normal question.